# Updating subscribe data during session in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to update the id passed to a subscribe parameter in Meteor - in short, I am wanting to subscribe to whatever the Collection object is with the id in the current url. I can get this to happen for first load, but not when a new object is created and the user is routed to that new object within their session.

The only way I have been able to get this to vaguely work is a hack using `setInterval` - not great I know, so am looking for the correct Meteor way.

Currently my `publications.js` in `server` is:

```
Meteor.publish('shares', function(id){
 return Shares.find({_id:id});
});
```

`router.js` is

```
Router.route('/share-social/:_id', {
 name: 'shareSocial',
 data: function() { return Shares.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

and subscribing via `main.js` in `client`: (ie, get the id in the url, and subscribe to that)

```
setInterval(function(){
 var x = location.href.split('/');
 var id = x.slice(-1).pop();
 Meteor.subscribe('shares', id);
}, 100);
```

and finally the template helper:

```
Template.shareSocial.helpers({
  shares: function() {
   return Shares.find().fetch();
 }
});
```

The above clearly has its issues. How do I reactively subscribe only to the object with the id that is displayed in the current url, whether it be in the same session or new session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of slicing the id from the URL, you could set up a reactive source for your subscription by defining current id to a Session variable, e.g.:

```js
// router.js
Router.route('/share-social/:_id', function() {
    Session.set('id', this.params._id);
    this.render('shareSocial');
});

// main.js
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('shares', Session.get('id'));
});
```

Now every time you change the id for your route, both the Session variable and subscription will be updated.